# After what time gc is called

Tags: java, playframework

I'm using the play framework. I want to keep alive one of my object everytime whether it is been used now or not because it will be used later.

Creating the object is a time taking process(contains 10L records). The object is gc'ed if it is not accessed for some time.

My idea is to access the object and keep it alive before it is gc'ed. I tried to access the object in a function with @Before annotation but it doesn't works. My primary idea is to keep alive of the object. If i know the after what time gc function is called then i can use job functionality in playframework to keep it alive.

Comment: GC isn't just time-driven, it's need- and reference-count-based.

Comment: @Dave Newton reachability-based, not reference-counted.

Comment: @EJP Okay, if there's something in the spec about GC implementation (I don't know).

Comment: @Dave Newton that's what garbage collection means. Is there anything there about reference counting?

Answer (score 4):

The garbage collector will only clean up an object if there is no longer a reference to the object. Your design should ensure that this particular object exists and is referenced by at least one variable to ensure it is not removed during garbage collection.

You might want to investigate using a Singleton-style design pattern here, it will make sure there's a reference to the object, but that there's only ever one object at a time.

That way, the object will not be garbage collected as it's being referenced by at least one variable.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think "I want to make sure this object stays alive." is an entirely different requirement from "I need to make one instance globally accessible and forbid other instances."

Comment: So, using a Singleton pattern, that will keep the object alive, is not going to solve the problem? What other suggestion would you have then? I thought this might be the simplest solution given the stated requirement.

Comment: The simplest solution is to just stick the object in a `static` field. Making a singleton adds completely irrelevant semantics and unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Interesting, that's how I feel about just using static - point taken though, Singleton is more complex, but I feel it leads to more thinking about design. I've seen too much code with static variables (and blocks of code) that was just horrible to simply revert to static whenever it appears to be the simplest solution. I will, however, re-evaluate my use of singletons to identify opportunities where static might just be more elegant.

Comment: [don't use singletons](http://jalf.dk/singleton/). Not even when you think it's the right solution. It isn't. As long as an object is reachable, it'll stay alive. If you just want to keep it alive, create a static reference to it. No need to bog down your code with antipatterns which (1) introduce undesirable semantics on the object, and (2) are complex enough that implementations nearly always contain subtle bugs, especially when used from multiple threads

Comment: Singletons don't lead to *any* thinking of design. That's practically their only purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to misunderstand how garbage collection works. If you're keeping a reference to your object around somewhere that you can hand it to a scheduled job, then that reference in itself will prevent the object from being collected. The only way this wouldn't apply is if you use a(n) [(evil) singleton object](http://www.google.com/search?q=evil%20singleton) to get a reference to the object in question, and periodically "touching" the object with a task won't inhibit garbage collection in that case. The simple solution there is to not use that (evil) pattern. The actual answer to your question is simply, "If you're not done with an object, then just don't let go of the reference to it." It's a quite natural solution.